# Why Notepad++ shows Carriage return + Line feed for both \r and \n

Tags: c#, .net, notepad++, carriage-return, linefeed

In C# define 4 variable as below:

```
string s1 = "\r";
string s2 = "\n";
string CarriageReturn = (Convert.ToChar(13)).ToString();
string LineFeed = (Convert.ToChar(10)).ToString();
```

Then by watching copy their value in Notepad++ and click on "Show all characters".  Interestingly you can see there is no difference between \r and \n and for both of them, it shows CR LF.
Is it a bug or something else? How can we explain this?

Comment: The Windows line ending is CRLF, so I would guess that Notepad++ is automatically doing this to each line.

Comment: Type into Notepad++ `test<enter>again<enter>try<enter>` (replacing `<enter>` with the Enter key on your keyboard) and repeat your *Show All Characters*. What do you see?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the values into Notepad++? For instance, are you writing the values to the console and copying them from there? Or, are you watching the values in a debugger window and then copying them to Notepad++? Or are you using another way? The more specific you are, the more likely it is that someone will provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Interestingly you can see there no difference with \r and \n and for both of them it shows CR LF Is it a bug or something else?

It is not a bug. CRLF is the default for the [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) in Windows: a 'string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.'

> How can we explain this?

It probably results from the way you are outputting the string values to a file. If you use a method that adds new lines, such as `WriteAllLines()` does, then there will automatically be a CRLF at the end of each value you write.

For instance, we can run the following program.

```
string r = "\r";
string n = "\n";
string CarriageReturn = (Convert.ToChar(13)).ToString();
string LineFeed = (Convert.ToChar(10)).ToString();

var content = new string[] {
    $"(r:{r})", 
    $"(n:{n})", 
    $"(13:{CarriageReturn})", 
    $"(10:{LineFeed})" 
};

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("output1.txt", content);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("output2.txt", string.Join("", content));
```

It produces two output files. The one on the left used `WriteAllLines` to write four lines. The one on the right used `WriteAllText()` and did not write any new lines.

[image]

In both, all of the content outside parentheses is independent of your code. That is, the `CRLF` symbols are part of writing a line in the call to `WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Sounds like they're not even outputting to a file in the first place, just copying the values off of the debugger or something? Your WriteAllLines() example does still write each CR and LF as is.

Comment: Hmm, can't be. Copying the values just copies their string representations, not the characters themselves.